# Create list of values from 2D dictionary if they show up less than a certain number of times

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

Given a dictionary in the following format:

```
nodes = {1: {'pos': (1, 2), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         2: {'pos': (2, 2), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         3: {'pos': (4, 3), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         4: {'pos': (5, 3), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         5: {'pos': (6, 3), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         6: {'pos': (1, 4), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         7: {'pos': (2, 4), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         8: {'pos': (4, 5), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         9: {'pos': (5, 5), 'other_data': 'N/A'},
         10: {'pos': (6, 5), 'other_data': 'N/A'}}
```

I would like to create a list or set of only the Y values of the position that show up less than 3 times. Maintaining the order is not important. The 'other_data' has been included yet shortened for the sake of readability.

So far I have this:

```
foo = [values.get('pos')[1] for values in nodes.values()]
bar = set(x for x in foo if foo.count(x) < 3)
print(bar)
```

This does give me the expected result:

```
{2, 4}
```

But I was hoping to find a more pythonic way or one that uses only a single line, as the way I am doing it now seems clunky.

Comment: 3 lines is pretty good, actually.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter` from `Collections`, and pass the list of y-values to the Counter, then you can either use list-comprehension and take only the keys with count less than 3, or you can use `filter` and filter out the values that you don't need:

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> [k for k,v in Counter(d['pos'][1] for d in nodes.values()).items() if v<3]
[2, 4]
```

Comment: not really readable code. 2 lines of code is better in my eyes